# jQuery Validation on large form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm creating a web app that comprises of one large form that the user submits to the server.

This form has standard jQuery validation and that works fine. (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

However, A section in the middle of the form will be required to be submitted via an ajax call. Lets say this section of the form has a simple "add" button -- Is it possible to validate only THIS section of the form when the add button is pressed?

And validate the rest of the form when submitted normally. I've looked through the jQuery Validation api and couldn't see anything.

I thought I could a manual call like:

```
$('#commentForm').validate({
    rules : {
        cname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    }
}).element("#cname");
```

Unfortunately, this adds validation that gets checked when the main submit button is pressed.

Any help or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: which validation fn.extend do you use here? http://plugins.jquery.com/validationengine/

Comment: Sorry - I'm using this one: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you. **[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W34hn/)**

HTML

```
  <form id="commentForm" method="post" action="index.php" style="font-family: Georgia">
     <fieldset>
        <legend>The main form</legend>
        <label for="text1">Text 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
        <br /><br />
        <fieldset id="opt">
           <legend>This section is only rquired when "Add" button is clicked</legend>
           <label for="text2">Text 2</label>
           <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" />
           <br /><br />
           <button id="add">Add</button>

        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <label for="text4">Text 4</label>

        <input type="text" id="text4" name="text4" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Post Main Form" />
     </fieldset>
  </form>
```

### JavaScript

```
        $('#commentForm').validate({
           //ignore everything in the sub-form
           ignore: '#opt *',
           rules: {
              text1: {
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 2
              },
              text4: {
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 2
              }
           }
        });

        $('#add').click(function () {

           var txt = $('#text2');

           //here you add validation rules for sub-form elements
           txt.rules('add', {
              required: true
           });

           //here you trigger the validation for elements in subform
           txt.valid();

           /* here you do your ajax stuff */

           return false;
        });
```

This approach jQuery validator plugin's `ignore` option as well as `.valid()` method to manually trigger validation on elements. I hope it helps.

This example was tested using `jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.10.0`

Comment: I think that's EXACTLY what I need! I was unaware that I could "ignore" certain elements with the plugin! Thanks a lot Ejay!